# 4 Errors in Android Studio while using Date Picker

Tags: java, android-studio

I wanted to pop-up data picker but, when I run the code 4 errors are shown below

1- E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.util.ArrayMap', referenced from method com.android.tools.fd.runtime.MonkeyPatcher.monkeyPatchExistingResources

2- 
E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.util.ArrayMap', referenced from method com.android.tools.fd.runtime.MonkeyPatcher.pruneResourceCache

3-E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.icu.util.Calendar
                      at com.example.quitme.Profile.onCreate(Profile.java:26)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

could anyone help me to solve errors?

Comment: `ArrayMap` is not available until API level 19.  On what platform version are you running?

Comment: first add your profile.java class and for the first and second issue try to invalidate cache

Comment: My platform version is 2.2.2

Comment: How can I invalidate cash ? could you explain more?